# Optimal index for query in OrientDB

Tags: sql, optimization, indexing, orientdb

I have the following query

```
SELECT FROM Post
WHERE activityLog IS NOT NULL
AND activityLog_pointerProcessed IS NULL
LIMIT 1000
```

The properties are defined as

```
CREATE PROPERTY Post.activityLog_pointerProcessed BOOLEAN
CREATE PROPERTY Post.activityLog EMBEDDEDMAP EMBEDDEDMAP
```

However, it seems to be running fairly slowly. I have added the following index

```
CREATE INDEX Post_activityLog_pointerProcessed
ON Post (activityLog, activityLog_pointerProcessed)
NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
```

I'm wondering if this is the optimal index for this scenario or if there's a different way to set this up. The Post class is still filling up but currently has 2 million rows. The query takes **~5-10 seconds** to run.

Here's what I get when I `explain` it

> orientdb {pumpup}> explain SELECT FROM Post WHERE activityLog IS NOT
>   NULL AND activityLog_pointerProcessed IS NULL LIMIT 1000
>
> Profiled command
>   '{documentReads:378236,current:#22:378235,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass:378236,recordReads:378236,fetchingFromTargetElapsed:337922,evaluated:378236,elapsed:337922.88,resultType:collection,resultSize:1000}'
>   in 338.688995 sec(s):
>   {"@type":"d","@version":0,"documentReads":378236,"current":"#22:378235","documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass":378236,"recordReads":378236,"fetchingFromTargetElapsed":337922,"evaluated":378236,"elapsed":337922.88,"resultType":"collection","resultSize":1000,"@fieldTypes":"documentReads=l,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,evaluated=l,elapsed=f"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the explain result, the index hasn't been used and 378,236 documents were scanned.

The activityLog property has been declared as an EMBEDDEDMAP, so the internal values are indexed, not the fact the collection is null. I don't think it will work, but make a try enabling null values on index:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes#null-values

Probably the best for this case is saving another boolean value "activityLog.empty" to be indexed and retrieve your query much faster.

```
CREATE PROPERTY Post.activityLogEmpty BOOLEAN
CREATE INDEX Post_activityLog_pointerProcessed ON Post (activityLogEmpty, activityLog_pointerProcessed) 
                                               NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
```

On creation set the property "activityLogEmpty" to FALSE and as soon as you populate the "activityLog" collection set it to true.

Comment: Perhaps there could be a way to say `select from index:Post_activityLog_pointerProcessed where key = [NOT NULL, NULL]` (after using `{ ignoreNullValues : false }`, as advised). You are right, running the query is no faster with that index set. It would be ideal if indexes worked with `NULL` values on `EMBEDDEDMAP`.